# How can I add to my page layout with code in the ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My page layout looks like this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="detailsLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</StackLayout>
```

When I create my ViewModel I pass in a pointer to the page. What I would like to do is this:

public class CardsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

```
    private readonly Cards cardsPage;

    public CardsViewModel(Cards cardsPage)
    {
        this.cardsPage = cardsPage;
    }

    async public Task CardBtn()
    {
        cardsPage.detailsLayout.Children.Clear();
```

But I don't have access to the detailsLayout due to its protection level.

Can someone tell me how I can get access to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example above is an example of coupling and breaking the separation between the `ViewModel` and the `View(Page)`. If you want to benefit from `MVVM` pattern - don't keep a reference to your UI layer and definitely don't try to manipulate the UI layer directly in the `ViewModel`.

What you should do instead is depends on your needs, however I can give you few ideas:

1. Encapsulate the logic within the UI control it self, exposing a delegate, command or property you could bind to from your `ViewModel` to trigger the specific event.
2. Keep the logic on UI layer, the Page itself and use a `MessagingCenter` to communicate to it from the `ViewModel`.

Good luck.

P.S.: You can find more information and examples about `MessagingCenter` in the [official Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center). Just don't forget to unsubscribe, otherwise you will find yourself in a bad place.

Comment: Thanks. About the 2nd option.  You mention a Messaging Center but in another area of the application I have passed a pointer to the page to the ViewModel and then called methods on the page using pagePointer.Method()  is that not a good idea and if not then do you have an example of how I could use MessagingCenter?

Comment: Yes, it is quite bad, for more information please re-read my answer. Regarding the MessagingCenter, I updated the answer.