# How can I modify my application from VM making direct calls to the back end C# to instead use Xamarin MessagingCenter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using ICommand like this but from what I understand it would be better to use the Xamarin MessagingCenter. Can someone suggest how I could change my code so as to use that and what changes would be needed.

```
public partial class SettingsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand OpenPageCmd { get; }
    public SettingsPageViewModel(SettingsPage settingsPage)
    {
        this.settingsPage = settingsPage;
        OpenPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) => settingsPage.OpenPage(pageType));
    }

public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{

    SettingsPageViewModel vm;

    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new SettingsPageViewModel(this);
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    public void OpenPage(string pageType)
    {  
    }
```

Comment: why not declare the OpenPage method in the view model and call directly from the when excuting command?

Comment: personally, I would never use messagincenter, unless you are required to when subscribing between different domain, but in most cases, mvvm design would give you access to where needed and also use of eventhandlers can sort of notify and pass eventargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I answered your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835121/how-can-i-add-to-my-page-layout-with-code-in-the-viewmodel) and I understand the context, though it will make sense if I will reply. The misconceptions should be clear at this point as the question is about how to improve this code.

`MessagingCenter` is easy to use and at the same time to misuse. You have to make sure to subscribe and unsubscribe properly. Usually you do so on `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing` methods. Here is an example:

```
public partial class SettingsPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand OpenPageCmd { get; }
    public SettingsPageViewModel()
    {
        OpenPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) =>   MessagingCenter.Send(new MyFirstMessage(pageType), MyFirstMessage.Message));
    }
}
public class MyFirstMessage
{
    public static readonly string Message = nameof(MyFirstMessage);
    public string PageType { get; }

    public MyFirstMessage(string pageType)
    {
        PageType = pageType;
    }
}

public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{
    SettingsPageViewModel vm;

    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new SettingsPageViewModel(this);
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

   protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, MyFirstMessage.Message, (MyFirstMessage obj) => OpenPage(obj.PageType));
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MyFirstMessage>(this, MyFirstMessage.Message);
    }

    void OpenPage(string pageType)
    {

    }
}
```

Beside that, I can spot at least another 2 issues in the provided example:

1. The `View(Page)` is still aware of the `ViewModel`.
2. It seems that you need a `NavigationService` instead of using `MessagingCenter`.

Both issues can be easily solved, but the solution is to long to type and involves different aspects. Therefore, I would recommend to check [architecture examples on github](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Mobile).

Comment: Thanks for your assistance and advice.  I'll remove the links between the Page and the ViewModel.  I have a few different types of commands so I will take your advice and look into using the Navigation Service.  Just a quick question. All my pages are tabbed pages so will that make any difference and will the NavigationService work okay with those?

Comment: Yes, NavigationService if you write and use it correctly should work with any type of navigation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a big misconception.
The point of MVVM is to separate the logic and the view of your app. Right here you are passing a reference of the page to the viewmodel, this breaks the whole idea of MVVM.

- OpenPageCmd should execute a method located in the viewmodel/businesslogic (which handles opening a new page)
- Remove "OpenPage(...)" in your ContentPage.
- You don't need the MessagingCenter at all in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

To only answer your question.

1. You need to Subscribe for a message in your `SettingsPage` code behind

   ```
   public SettingsPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       vm = new SettingsPageViewModel(this);
       BindingContext = vm;

       MessagingCenter.Subscribe<SettingsPageViewModel, string>(this, "NavigateToSettings", 
           NavigateToSettingsAction);
   }


   private void NavigateToSettingsAction(MainViewModel obj, string pageType)
   {
       OpenPage(pageType);
   }

   public void OpenPage(string pageType)
   {  
   }
   ```
2. Send Message from within the `OpenPageCmd` command in `SettingsPageViewModel`

   ```
   public SettingsPageViewModel()
   {
       OpenPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) => { MessagingCenter.Send(this, "NavigateToSettings", pageType); });
   }
   ```

the code above should achieve what you need. Keep in mind, you should never reference any `View` from within `ViewModel` like you did. And my own approach is to Navigate using a Navigation Service but this is a whole other story.

EDIT

Here is a link to an example of implementing Navigation Service using MVVMLight

https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-navigation-with-mvvm-light

Comment: I am using just one command to open different pages and I pass the page name as a parameter. Can you show how I could do this with your example as I am not sure how I can pass and receive that parameter.

Comment: The other answer suggested not using MessagingCenter. What's your opinion on that.  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2 I edited the answer, added Parameter and also added a link for an example of implementing NavigationService which is much better than your current approach and it complies with what "Csharpest" said in his answer.